# A problem about time varying domain in Chen Wenxiong and Li Congming 's study on $-\Delta u=\exp u$ in $R^2$ and $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x< +\infty$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I'm considering a problem about time varying domain in Chen Wenxiong and Li Congming 's study on $-\Delta u=\exp u$ in $R^2$ and $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x< +\infty$.

LEMMA 1.1 (Ding). If $u$ is a solution of $-\Delta u=\exp u$ in $R^2$ and $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x<$ $+\infty$, then $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x \geqslant 8 \pi$.

Proof. For $-\infty<t<\infty$ let $\Omega_t=\{x \mid u(x)>t\}$; one can obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x & =-\int_{\Omega_t} \Delta u=\int_{\partial \Omega_t}|\nabla u| d s \\
-\frac{d}{d t}\left|\Omega_t\right| & =\int_{\partial \Omega_t} \frac{d s}{|\nabla u|} .
\end{aligned}
$$
By the Schwarz inequality and the isoperimetric inequality,
$$
\int_{\partial \Omega_t} \frac{d s}{|\nabla u|} \cdot \int_{\partial \Omega_t}|\nabla u| \geqslant\left|\partial \Omega_t\right|^2 \geqslant 4 \pi\left|\Omega_t\right| .
$$
Hence
$$
-\left(\frac{d}{d t}\left|\Omega_t\right|\right) \cdot \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x \geqslant 4 \pi\left|\Omega_t\right|
$$
and so
$$
\frac{d}{d t}\left(\int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x\right)^2=2 \exp t \cdot\left(\frac{d}{d t}\left|\Omega_t\right|\right) \cdot \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x \leqslant-8 \pi \exp t \cdot\left|\Omega_t\right| .
$$
Integrating from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ gives
$$\tag{1}
-\left(\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x\right)^2 \leqslant-8 \pi \int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x
$$
which implies $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x \geqslant 8 \pi$ as desired.

**The proof details before (1) is presented by the discussions between me and other users in [Differentiation in time varying domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528507/differentiation-in-time-varying-domain/4677803#4677803), I'm confused about the last step, how they integrate from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?**

In detail, for the LHS, how to compute the limit of $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x$ and $lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x$, I think $lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x$ must be $\int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x$ but I don't know how to deal with $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x$, from the fact that $lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x = \int_{R^2} \exp u(x) d x$ which is bounded and $\frac{d}{d t}\left(\int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x\right)^2=2 \exp t \cdot\left(\frac{d}{d t}\left|\Omega_t\right|\right) \cdot \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x \leqslant 0 $ we know that when $t \rightarrow +\infty$, $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \int_{\Omega_t} \exp u(x) d x$ is also bounded, but based on the proof, it seems that it is 0.

For the RHS, how to integrate $\exp t \cdot\left|\Omega_t\right|$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$? I try to use  Reynolds transport theorem
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} t} \int_{\Omega(t)} \mathbf{A}(\boldsymbol{x}, t) \mathrm{d}^n \boldsymbol{x}=\int_{\partial \Omega(t)}(\boldsymbol{V}(\boldsymbol{x}, t) \cdot \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x}, t)) \mathbf{A}(\boldsymbol{x}, t) \mathrm{d}^{n-1} \boldsymbol{x}+\int_{\Omega(t)} \partial_t \mathbf{A}(\boldsymbol{x}, t) \mathrm{d}^n \boldsymbol{x}
$$
I set $A_1=e^u$ and $A_2=e^t$, because on $\partial \Omega(t)$ we have $u=t$ so we have
$$\exp t \cdot\left|\Omega_t\right|=
\int_{\Omega t} e^t d x =\frac{d}{d t} \int_{\Omega t} e^t d x - \frac{d}{d t}\int_{\Omega t} e^u d x 
$$
Now we have to face another question which is $lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \exp t \cdot\left|\Omega_t\right|$ and $lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \exp t \cdot\left|\Omega_t\right|$

Answer (score 1):

For your first question: If you want to understand why $\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_{\Omega_t} exp(u(x)) dx=0$, just rewrite using the indicator function
$\lim_{t\to+\infty}\int_{\Omega_t} exp(u(x)) dx$$=\lim_{t\to +\infty}\int \chi_{\Omega_t} exp(u(x)) dx$ and observe that the right-hand side converges by the monotone convergence theorem towards $0$. Remember that the indicator functions $\chi_{\Omega_t}(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $t\to\infty$.
The rest of your questions are probably answered in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4528507/differentiation-in-time-varying-domain?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Another user kindly post another answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/453099/time-varying-domain-in-chen-wenxiong-and-li-congming-s-study-on-delta-u-exp/453107#453107.